# CadClientInterface.powerUp() hangs while connecting smart card using Serial Port

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I am trying to connect to my smart card using serial port using below code:

```
String port = "COM1"; // serial port
CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(port);

String appname = "CadClient";
int timeout = 30000;

CommPort commPort = portId.open(appname, timeout);              
InputStream is = commPort.getInputStream(); 
OutputStream os = commPort.getOutputStream();

cad = CadDevice.getCadClientInstance(CadDevice.PROTOCOL_T1, is, os);

//...hangs here for unlimited time
cad.powerUp();
```

Any help why it stuck at powerUp(). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to your device properties and check the "Do not open APDU console" checkbox.

This should be something like this :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input however i dont see this option. Can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: What IDE do you use ? And what simulator?

Comment: i am using eclipse IDE and using physical device: omni smart card

Comment: Does your device appear in IDE ? ( I edited my answer with some pictures).

Comment: Thanks for your effort however this option only appears for simulator NOT actual device.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for it to hang is that the card is not answering to reset i.e. ATR is not received from the card. This is done on powerUP().

This could be due to non-open port or port being used by some other APDU client.

Comment: I assume the port is opened by cadClient only once, however how to make sure for this?

Comment: I believe that PORT is open (for service) by some cad device or running simulator. Your code here is a client to connect to that port and thereby, sending the APDU's to the running service.

Comment: so what you suggest please?